# Many to many relation, multi where clause on the same column and hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, derby

Sorry for the bad question title, couldnt think of anything better.

Anyway, my tables are Tags - Poststags - Posts. Poststags is a junction table for many to many relation. I need to select all posts with given tags, I dont know how many tags the user will choose to search for. One way I found to do this is in the code below, however i would need to loop all the tags given by the user and construct the query string from there since the number of tags is unknown. Seems like a pretty bad solution to me.

Another solution would be to store all tags in one column in the Posts table as a pure string, but I dont want to do that because of other application requirements.

I have a working sql query, since I was trying pure sql before trying to implement it in hibernate, but I dont like doing a select of all posts containing each tag and then joining each query, is there a way to specify the same column multiple times in the WHERE clause? Something along the lines WHERE pt.tag_id = x AND pt.tag_id = y? (I know this won't work). IN operator won't work either since it will give me Posts that contain any of the supplied tags and not just the posts containing ALL of the supplied tags.

Also how would I implement such a query in HQL(if subqueries like this are even supported?). Or can I somehow manage this via criteria? Or do I have to resort to using createSQLQuery method of a hibernate session?

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT * FROM posts p
inner join poststags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
WHERE pt.tag_id = 1 ) AS A
INNER JOIN
( SELECT * FROM posts p
inner join poststags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
WHERE pt.tag_id = 2 ) AS B ON A.id = B.id
```

And yes, I know this query is not returning the Post entity itself, but I can handle that later.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hibernate or ORM for this kind of complex select, it may work, but in a bad way.

Your use case should be solved by full text search, which means each Post will need have its own tags.

I don't see much value to make Tag an entity. It's just a string.

Full text search could be heavy for database , A better way is using elasticsearch to help. Spring has integration with spring-data-elasticsearch and it's not difficult to use. Elasyicsearch is very powerful for free text search.

Comment: The Tag entity stores more than just a name, most importantly its type and number of posts. What is the "bad way" its gonna work in? And I dont need to do any search this way except querying the Tags table for suggestions as the user types the tags in. The way my app is set up, I have multiple Entities, each with its own data access object behind an interface which define simple CRUD methods that cover all my needs, this is the only complex query in the project and not using ORM would make the rest of the project harder.

Comment: I see problems with number of post fields. Considering the following scenarios: You have two tags: Java and SQL. Post A is adding Java Tag, remove SQL tag; Post B adding SQL tag and remove Java tag. It could cause deadlock.

Comment: the problem of ORM is that you cannot anticipate the queries they generated without deep understanding of how they works. N+1 is a common issue and you need keep monitoring number of sql generated by hibernate. But, this is not a concern if you use native query.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you properly, if Post A removes SQL tag, only thing that gets removed is in the junction table and the Tag itself stays for Post B to use. Also you recommend using a native query for this then?

Comment: 1. I think I misunderstood you on numbers of post, I thought you have a field. Do monitor how many queries generated by hibernate when you get number of Post when list<Post>. If I am not wrong, it will fetch all posts even you only want to know the size. 2. Yes, native query is better than HQL or JPQL. But there should be a better query.

Comment: The performance won't good, full index scan will happen. I didn't test this, basic idea is to use group_concat.

SELECT pt.post_id
FROM PostTags pt
where GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) like '<your pre fetched tag id>'
GROUP BY pt.post_id
order by pt.tag_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that 'should' work using Criteria queries in Hibernate.

Assuming that you have an entity for Post and an entity for PostTag and PostTag has reference to Post (which I think it should given the example query that you provided), I believe that something like this should do what you want:

```
static DetachedCriteria getPostTagCriteria(String tagString)
{
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PostTag.class, "uniqueName_" + postTagId);
    criteria.createAlias("tag", "tag");

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tag.tagString", tagString));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("postId"));

    return criteria;
}

static List<Post> getPosts(List<String> tagStrings)
{
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Post.class, "post");

    for(String tagString : tagStrings)
    {
        criteria.add(Property.forName("post.id").in(getPostTagCriteria(tagString)));
    }

    List<Post> ret = criteria.list();
    return ret;
}
```

This assumes that you have reasonable entities to represent Post, PostTag and Tag and that they all reference each other in obvious parent/child sort of ways that I have completely made up here.

But, the general idea of creating multiple detached criteria objects based on your input should solve your problem.  This solution also comes with the same caveats regarding SQL complexity mentioned above.  You will be creating a sub-query for each tag passed in.  So, depending on your indexes and table sizes, you may need to consider a different approach.